# Download zip file servlet with contentLength

Tags: java, download, http-content-length

I am trying to write a servlet to download files as a zip, which will read multiple nodes in a repository (CRX) to get Inputstream of multiple images.

I am using ZipOutputStream to download the zip file.
But as the length after zipping is not known, I can't set the content-length header in response, hence the browser is not able to show the remaining time to download.

Current code:

```
String[] paths = request.getRequestParameters("path");
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
for (int i=0; i<paths.length;i++){
    InputStream is = getStream(paths[i]);
    IOUtils.copy(is, out);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
    out.closeEntry();
}
```

Is there a way to generate the ZipFile and then write to the output stream?